# Quantstrat and Windows

Tags: r, quantstrat, blotter

I've looked at previous correspondence, have followed the advice but am still unable to install quantstrat and blotter. I'm at a loss. Perhaps I've missed a previous post which would help and would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. Many thanks.

Actions: I downloaded the quantstrat pack and issued the following command:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/George/Downloads/quantstrat_0.9.1669.tar", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

The result was the following:

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/George/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning: invalid package 'C:/Users/George/Downloads/quantstrat_0.9.1669.tar'
>   Error: ERROR: no packages specified
>   Warning in install.packages :
>   running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\George\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "C:/Users/George/Downloads/quantstrat_0.9.1669.tar"' had status 1
>   Warning in install.packages :
>   installation of package ‘C:/Users/George/Downloads/quantstrat_0.9.1669.tar’ had non-zero exit status

I should add that I have Rx64 3.2 installed.

Success, cracked the problem. I downloaded the *.zip version* of quantstrat and blotter (currently both are 3.1.3) and both installed successfully. Interesting.

I notice there is no supporting documentation - is that the case? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. This site doesn't work like a usual forum where you start a conversation. People here expect you to formulate a  concise question for a specific problem. In your case please describe the exact problem you encounter while installing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your issue and good to see you already worked this out yourself. You could post your solution as an answer here to make it findable by others. (answered questions are highlighted in the search result list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was: I downloaded the .zip version of quantstrat and blotter (currently both are 3.1.3) and both installed successfully. Interesting.